# Could please let me know the Explanation s.replaceAll("\\S", " ")

Tags: regex, string, replaceall

```
String s="Swamy Application";
s=s.replaceAll("\\S"," ");
system.out.println(s);
```

Should return String but we are getting empty 
I need explanation What happening in `\\S`.

Comment: RT*M. What did you mean the code to do when you wrote it?

Comment: \S matches any non-whitespace character: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: use `\\s` instead

Answer (score 0):

`String.replaceAll()` takes a regex as first parameter and the replacement text for all matches of that regex as second parameter. Here, you have given `\\S` as the first parameter, which matches every non-whitespace character. The replacement string given is a whitespace. So the returned String would be having whitespaces only.

Comment: Yeah , Thanks  @Naveed S

Answer (score 0):

\S matches any non-whitespace character which is leading to replace the alpha characters in the string to whitespace.

"Swamy Application" -> "                  "

More about this at [source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)

If you are trying to replace the whitespace character from the string then use:

"\s"

else if you are trying to replace the only S character from the string then use:

"S"